# Amasty OneStepCheckout for Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

I'm using Amasty onestepcheckout on magento 1.
I'm getting issue with shipping rates.
By default i have enable Billing and shipping address same.
Ship to this address option is enable. So, when billing and shipping address are same and i change city or any other address field then shipping rates are not updating.

But when billing and shipping address are different then shipping rates are updating properly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Contact Amasty, this seems like a fault in their code. (Unless, of course, you've modified anthing)